# Concatenating method call results

Tags: python, python-3.x

First question ever on stack**overflow**. I hope I'm following protocol.

Beginner at Python.
Windows 10 - v3.6.10.

I'm having a hard time concatenating method call results. I have this working...

```
logging.info(f'PROCESSING {IMPORT_FILE.upper()} - ' + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(IMPORT_FILE)) )
```

...and am trying to add this ...

```
arcpy.management.GetCount(in_rows = IMPORT_FILE)
```

I've tried many ways with different positions of the round brackets as I possible could. For example:

```
logging.info(f'PROCESSING {IMPORT_FILE.upper()} - ' + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(IMPORT_FILE)) + arcpy.management.GetCount(in_rows = IMPORT_FILE) )
```

I'd like to know an answer to my specific question but invite a better way of accomplishing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I'd like to know an answer to my specific question" - well, what _is_ the question?

Comment: What isn't working, exactly?

Comment: I advise against using the `+` operator for string concatenation. You are already using f-strings, so continue to do so.

Comment: To clarify all of this ... [1] **Syntax** -- Your immediate problem is that `GetCount` returns an `int`; you have to convert it to `str` for concatenation.  [2] **Programming style** -- Don't use simple `+` concatenation.  Instead, return to your tutorials on output formatting.  Use a consistent f-string for all the values.

Comment: "I hope I'm following protocol" - this [ask] and this [mre] will help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions from those able to derive what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that understand you correctly, but maybe this will work:

```py
logging.info(f'PROCESSING {IMPORT_FILE.upper()} - {time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(IMPORT_FILE))} {arcpy.management.GetCount(in_rows = IMPORT_FILE)}')
```

And also try to avoid strings concatenation using `+`-operation, because strings are immutable in Python, so each `+` operator allocates new piece of memory. In this case it's not really critical issue, but it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example works, because `ctime` returns a string, but `GetCount` most likely returns a number. In Python, you can not "add" numbers to strings directly, but have to convert them to `str` explicitly first.

```
logging.info(f'PROCESSING {IMPORT_FILE.upper()} - ' + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(IMPORT_FILE)) + str(arcpy.management.GetCount(in_rows = IMPORT_FILE)) )
```

But a much better approach would be to use proper string formatting. In fact, you already use `f`-strings for the first parameter, so just use them for the others, too:

```
logging.info(f'PROCESSING {IMPORT_FILE.upper()} - {time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(IMPORT_FILE))} {arcpy.management.GetCount(in_rows = IMPORT_FILE)}')
```

Comment: The first example does indeed work. I understand what your saying with your example. Thanks

Comment: @Dennis Right, I did not realize `time.ctime` returns a string, confused it with `time.time`.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, once you pointed out what was returned it was clear for me.